# How to create a temp git repo from svn branch

Tags: git

There is an svn branch that I want to import to git; no need the whole svn repo, just a specific svn branch with its commits.

How to create such a temp git repo from svn branch?

Answer (score 1):

git provides the [`git svn`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn) command. You will find several methods to work on branches. Try and pick the best one for you

From the doc

```
# Clone a repo (like git clone):
    git svn clone http://svn.example.com/project/trunk
```

Comment: thanks - does `git svn` requires some new version of git? Mine is 1.9.1 but when I type in your command `git svn clone` it says `git: 'svn' is not a git command`